# Calling a function From a class with self arguments

Tags: python, class

```
class Login(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Login,self).__init__()
        loadUi("gui.ui",self)
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.stop)

    def start(self):
        self.lcdNumber_4.display(0)
```

I'm trying to call `start` from outside the class
I have tried:

```
login = Login()
login.start()
```

I think it has to do with the `QMainWindow` argument it takes

Comment: You say "like such:" and follow it up with nothing.

Comment: The `c` class should not inherit from `self` (which is undefined) but from an existing class type. It's also not clear why are you using the `pyqt` tag.

Comment: sorry it was just a test program im just trying to figure this out for my main application gui

Comment: @Jayke: You can still edit a closed post, and if you fix the problems that got it closed, it can be reopened.

Comment: @Jayke even assuming your code was correct (which isn't, so please verify you're properly [formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) and check the syntax and indentation when you [edit] it), it should do what you ask. But I believe you're just trying to call that `startfunction` from elsewhere, after the instance you're *actually* using has already been created. In that case, it'd be pointless, as you're calling that function for ***another*** instance. Unfortunately, what you provided is completely insufficient, I suggest to edit your post and provide a [mre] we could help you with

Comment: hey @Jayke. Welcome to SO. I edited your question. Please read my edit comment in the edit history to get some insights into why I edited it :)

Comment: Also, `QMainWindow ` is not an argument in this example, because Login is not a function. Its a class. And in classes, the values you add in parantheses are its super classes (the classes it inherits from). If you already want to tackle object oriented programming (OOP), you should probably spend some time in a course aboutOOP. But to be honest, it looks to me like maybe you should first study the fundamentals before going for OOP

Answer (score 0):

```
class c(self):
```

is nonsensical. It says the new class `c` inherits from whatever is stored in some outside variable named `self`, which probably doesn't exist (triggering a `NameError`). Just change it to:

```
class c:
```

and it will work as written.

Comment: i have functions in  class Login(QMainWindow): how can i access them from outside

Comment: @Jayke: There is *nothing* about that in your question. I'm not psychic; I can't intuit what's wrong with code you haven't shown, or even mentioned until now.

Comment: i just fixed the code sorry it was my first time using the site

Comment: @Jayke: Construct an instance of `Login`, then call `instance_name.startfunction()`? Just like you did in your original trimmed down code.

Comment: i have tried this but it will not work i think because of QMainWindow argument it needs

Comment: @Jayke: `QMainWindow` is what `Login` inherits from, it's not an argument at all. You really need to learn Python basics (from end-to-end tutorial, an actual class, etc.) before you start trying to do complicated stuff with GUIs. If you have no idea what inheritance even is, you clearly have no idea what the code you copied even does, you're just engaged in [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)/[copy-and-paste programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-and-paste_programming).